# FullZoom.setZoom is not a function Firefox Webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

EDIT: Problem experienced on macOS Sierra Version 10.12.2, Firefox 51.0.1, MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015). Have tried on my Toshiba Satellite P50TA with the same version Firefox and it works.

I'm looking at the firefox web extension tutorials https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master in particular tabs-tabs-tabs.

```
/// Zoom constants. Define Max, Min, increment and default values
const ZOOM_INCREMENT = 0.2;
const MAX_ZOOM = 3;
const MIN_ZOOM = 0.3;
const DEFAULT_ZOOM = 1;

function firstUnpinnedTab(tabs) {
  for (var tab of tabs) {
    if (!tab.pinned) {
      return tab.index;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * listTabs to switch to
 */
function listTabs() {
  getCurrentWindowTabs().then((tabs) => {
    let tabsList = document.getElementById('tabs-list');
    let currentTabs = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let limit = 5;
    let counter = 0;

    tabsList.textContent = '';

    for (let tab of tabs) {
      if (!tab.active && counter <= limit) {
        let tabLink = document.createElement('a');

        tabLink.textContent = tab.title || tab.id;
        tabLink.setAttribute('href', tab.id);
        tabLink.classList.add('switch-tabs');
        currentTabs.appendChild(tabLink);
      }

      counter += 1;
    }

    tabsList.appendChild(currentTabs);
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", listTabs);

function getCurrentWindowTabs() {
  return browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true});
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  function callOnActiveTab(callback) {
    getCurrentWindowTabs().then((tabs) => {
      for (var tab of tabs) {
        if (tab.active) {
          callback(tab, tabs);
        }
      }
    });
}

  if (e.target.id === "tabs-move-beginning") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab, tabs) => {
      var index = 0;
      if (!tab.pinned) {
        index = firstUnpinnedTab(tabs);
      }
      console.log(`moving ${tab.id} to ${index}`)
      browser.tabs.move([tab.id], {index});
    });
  }

  if (e.target.id === "tabs-move-end") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab, tabs) => {
      var index = -1;
      if (tab.pinned) {
        var lastPinnedTab = Math.max(0, firstUnpinnedTab(tabs) - 1);
        index = lastPinnedTab;
      }
      browser.tabs.move([tab.id], {index});
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-duplicate") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      browser.tabs.duplicate(tab.id);
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-reload") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      browser.tabs.reload(tab.id);
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-remove") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-create") {
    browser.tabs.create({url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions"});
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-alertinfo") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      let props = "";
      for (let item in tab) {
        props += `${ item } = ${ tab[item] } \n`;
      }
      alert(props);
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-add-zoom") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      var gettingZoom = browser.tabs.getZoom(tab.id);
      gettingZoom.then((zoomFactor) => {
        //the maximum zoomFactor is 3, it can't go higher
        if (zoomFactor >= MAX_ZOOM) {
          alert("Tab zoom factor is already at max!");
        } else {
          var newZoomFactor = zoomFactor + ZOOM_INCREMENT;
          //if the newZoomFactor is set to higher than the max accepted
          //it won't change, and will never alert that it's at maximum
          newZoomFactor = newZoomFactor > MAX_ZOOM ? MAX_ZOOM : newZoomFactor;
          browser.tabs.setZoom(tab.id, newZoomFactor);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-decrease-zoom") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      var gettingZoom = browser.tabs.getZoom(tab.id);
      gettingZoom.then((zoomFactor) => {
        //the minimum zoomFactor is 0.3, it can't go lower
        if (zoomFactor <= MIN_ZOOM) {
          alert("Tab zoom factor is already at minimum!");
        } else {
          var newZoomFactor = zoomFactor - ZOOM_INCREMENT;
          //if the newZoomFactor is set to lower than the min accepted
          //it won't change, and will never alert that it's at minimum
          newZoomFactor = newZoomFactor < MIN_ZOOM ? MIN_ZOOM : newZoomFactor;
          browser.tabs.setZoom(tab.id, newZoomFactor);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-default-zoom") {
    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
      var gettingZoom = browser.tabs.getZoom(tab.id);
      gettingZoom.then((zoomFactor) => {
        if (zoomFactor == DEFAULT_ZOOM) {
          alert("Tab zoom is already at the default zoom factor");
        } else {
          browser.tabs.setZoom(tab.id, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        }
      });
    });
  }
  // Currently (11/2/2016) only supported by Chrome
  else if (e.target.id === "tabs-highlight") { // highlights current tab and next tab (cycles back to first tab if current tab is the last one)
    callOnActiveTab((tab, tabs) => {
      next = (tab.index+1) % tabs.length;
      browser.tabs.highlight({tabs:[tab.index, next]});
    });
  }

  else if (e.target.classList.contains('switch-tabs')) {
    var tabId = +e.target.getAttribute('href');

    chrome.tabs.query({
      currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
      for (var tab of tabs) {
        if (tab.id === tabId) {
          chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
              active: true
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});

//onRemoved listener. fired when tab is removed
browser.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo){
  console.log(`The tab with id: ${tabId}, is closing`);

  if(removeInfo.isWindowClosing) {
    console.log(`Its window is also closing.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Its window is not closing`);
  }
});

//onMoved listener. fired when tab is moved into the same window
browser.tabs.onMoved.addListener(function(tabId, moveInfo){
  var startIndex = moveInfo.fromIndex;
  var endIndex = moveInfo.toIndex;
  console.log(`Tab with id: ${tabId} moved from index: ${startIndex} to index: ${endIndex}`);
});
```

None of the zoom methods work and the browser console logs the comment that FullZoom.setZoom is not a function. This seems to be related to the update to Firefox 51.0.1 This is true of my own attempts to write simple web extensions that use cookies to remember zoom settings that are set with an onUpdated event.

The function still appears in the api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/setZoom

Comment: As downloaded a few minutes ago, the zoom functions in the [tabs-tabs-tabs](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/tabs-tabs-tabs) example work fine for me in a stock Firefox 51.01 (32 bit) on Windows 10 (64 bit) when loaded as a temporary add-on. I see no extraneous messages in the Browser Console. Thus, you are going to need to provided more information so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Using cookies to store this information does not appear to be the best way to do so for various reasons. You should consider using [`storage.local` or `storage.sync`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage).

Comment: Thanks makyen, I have just tested the tabs-tabs-tabs example on my windows 10 machine and it works fine. It would appear to be a mac problem as that is where I initially tested the extension.

Comment: Regarding the cookies, yes I will rewrite it using storage.local and get some practice using both cookies and storage.

Comment: Any news on this? I am experiencing the same issue.